# Place boxplots on a graph (as points)

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have data from samples at different times. I am using R and I don't know how to plot a boxplot from my data, where the boxes respects the distance at each time:
For exemple, a box of sample at time T = 0 must be on axis x = 0, another at T = 20 must be on axis X = 20.
Something like that :

[image]

Do you know if it is possible, with ggplot by example ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`? So we can help you better.

Answer (score 1):

How you do this depends on what format your data is in, which is why we would recommend including sample data with your question. Your data will almost certainly be in either long format or wide format.

If your data is in long format like this:

```r
set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(time = rep(c(0, 5, 20), 20), values = rnorm(60))

head(df)
#>   time     values
#> 1    0 -0.6264538
#> 2    5  0.1836433
#> 3   20 -0.8356286
#> 4    0  1.5952808
#> 5    5  0.3295078
#> 6   20 -0.8204684
```

Then you can do

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = time, y = values, group = time)) + geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

If your data is in wide format like this:

```r
set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(T0 = rnorm(20), T5 = rnorm(20), T20 = rnorm(20))

head(df)
#>           T0          T5        T20
#> 1 -0.6264538  0.91897737 -0.1645236
#> 2  0.1836433  0.78213630 -0.2533617
#> 3 -0.8356286  0.07456498  0.6969634
#> 4  1.5952808 -1.98935170  0.5566632
#> 5  0.3295078  0.61982575 -0.6887557
#> 6 -0.8204684 -0.05612874 -0.7074952
```

Then you need to pivot into long format before you plot, like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = 'time', values_to = 'values') %>%
  mutate(time = as.numeric(gsub('\\D', '', time))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = time, y = values, group = time)) + 
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]